# Shell script merge multiple CSV files depending on file naming pattern

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I have multiple csv files naming convention like A_1.csv , A_2.csv, B_1.csv, C_2.csv like this. All files have same header. Now I want to merge all files like below logic
If _1.csv exists I will take it and ignore _2.csv pattern with same alphabet. Both patterns are optional either _1 or _2 must be present with alphabet, From above I will merge A_1.csv (ignoring A_2.csv)+ B_1.csv + C_2.csv into a single file called final.csv file with single header using shell script.

I'm using below for merging all files with single header

```
cat A_1.csv <(tail +2 B_1.csv) <(tail +2 C_2.csv) > final.csv
```

but not getting the logic for alternative file pattern

Comment: What did you try already and where do you get stuck?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Added now cat A_1.csv <(tail +2 B_1.csv) <(tail +2 C_2.csv) > final.csv